# Можете ли вы определить как называется цветовая тема для редактора кода?

Tags: visual-studio-code, оформление

Попалось на глаза видео от Хауди Хо. Понравилось оформление редактора, хочу установить себе такое же. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется эта тема?
[image: скриншот из видео]
[image: Еще один скриншот]

Comment: Количество тем в vs code довольно велико, мне кажется проще в комментариях под видео спросить.